# Is ELM pass by reference or pass by value?

Tags: pass-by-reference, elm, internals

I'm playing around with ELM, and I wanted to clarify whether it is pass by value or pass by reference. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Are you sure you're wondering about value vs reference? Or are you actually wondering about eager vs lazy evaluation or arguments, which is one of the differences between Elm and Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Markus said, everything is immutable in Elm, so you don't really need to be concerned about reference vs value.

Conceptually, everything is passed by value and references do not exist. Compiled code will however pass references around because it's faster and because that's just what JS does. The situation might change when/if Elm starts compiling to WASM or other languages.

Answer (score 4):

In a language like Elm where everything is immutable, there is no difference between pass by value and pass by reference.

Comment: To clarify, in Elm there is no such thing as passing by reference, so everything is passed as a value :)